# How to validate url in java?

Tags: java, validation, jsf-2

I have one inputtext Where I have to enter a link .
How I am going to validate that string is a url(link) or not.
Example-

```
Pattern p = Pattern
                .compile("(@)?(href=')?(HREF=')?(HREF=\")?(href=\")?(http://)?[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+(\\.\\w[a-zA-Z_0-9\\-]+)+(/[#&\\n\\-=?\\+\\%/\\.\\w]+)?");

        Matcher m = p.matcher("https://mail.google.com");
        System.out.println(m.matches());
```

This code gives also false.I am not getting what was the problem in that code.
Or please refer another logic to validate the url.
I had already used `UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();` 
But I dont want to use this .jar

This is the another method this method validate properly but I that url is not available.How to check this requirement?
example-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String b = "http://11155555.com/";
        System.out.println(isUrl(b));

    }

    public static boolean isUrl(String str) {
        Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile(
                "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file):((//)|(\\\\\\\\))+[\\\\w\\\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\\\+-=\\\\\\\\\\\\.&]*)",
                Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = urlPattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Java is to Javascript as ham is to hamster. Please pay attention to your tags.

Comment: `URL` has a [`String` constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String)) that throws a `MalformedURLException`...

Answer (score -1):

Try this one :

```
 public static boolean isUrl(String str){
    Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile("((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file):((//)|(\\\\\\\\))+[\\\\w\\\\d:#@%/;$()~_?\\\\+-=\\\\\\\\\\\\.&]*)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
         Matcher matcher = urlPattern.matcher(str);
    if (matcher.find()) 
             return true;
        else
            return false;
}
```

Comment: This function gives required output but this is correct method to check?

Comment: @vijayk Yes what is the problem with that ?

Comment: I just confirm . I dont have problem.

Comment: also find the another solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15009573/url-validation-in-java

Comment: Suppose this is the example http://11155555.com which is return true but this is not a valid url. Then how can you check it?

Comment: @vijayk your link is not available.

Comment: please find http://1111.com is available on internet. so it may possible this type of sites are available.

Comment: this method check's only URL is valid. it not checks weather it is available or not on internet.

Comment: @keval-- If want to check the urls like www.google.com then what I want change the code? I dont want to check http:// character..